# Deploy Salesforce Shield components in production sandbox

Tags: shield-encryption, eventlogfile, shield

I have developed and tested transaction security policies in the sandbox environment. Can someone provide guidance around how to deploy these policies in production environment?

For Platform Encryption and Event Monitoring, can these two components be enabled directly in production environment? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Now you can take your encryption settings with you when you [deploy](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_security_pe_change_sets.htm) customizations from one org to another. You can also apply encryption to components that are already part of a change set. Your encryption settings are applied to the target org when your change set is uploaded to your target org.

Most customers try Shield Platform Encryption features in a sandbox before using them in production orgs.

> Basically you could do it either ways by enabling it in production or
>   preferably by deploying using change sets or IDE. When you
>   deploy Shield Platform Encryption to your org with a tool such as
>   Force.com IDE, Migration Tool, or Workbench, the Encrypted field
>   attribute persists. However, if you deploy to orgs with different
>   encryption settings, the effect depends on whether [Shield Platform
>   Encryption](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/216/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_platform_encryption_implementation_guide.pdf) is enabled in the target org.

Regardless of how you deploy, Salesforce automatically checks to see if the implementation violates Shield Platform Encryption guidelines.

[image]